# how to use a desktop software without having sql server installed on system?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

consider I write a desktop software in C# for example,and it reads/writes data to/from sql server,Can I run this software on a system without having sql server installed.

I saw the two links of stackoverflow,but did not get my answer.

I want to know CAN THAT BE DONE OR NOT?

if yes,how?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you wondering if you can remotely use an SQL server installed on another machine, or whether SQL Server will magically work even if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I want to sell my software and my software uses sql server,do my customers have to install sql server on their labtops?

Comment: The SQL server must be available somewhere in the (inter)network. But does not have to be installed on the machine itself.

Comment: Ah, you best have a look at SQL Server Express then.. Its free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sql Server must be installed, and running, *somewhere* to be able to use it. However, this does not need to be on local machine. The most common scenario for Sql Server is to be installed on a dedicated server machine off in a data center somewhere, and either many clients will connect to and use the same database, or one or a few web servers will connect potentially many times per second with different requests. It's not really intended for desktop use.

If you want to build a desktop app, and you want a database to use only as a local data store, Sql Server is actually a *really poor choice* for this. That includes the free Sql Server Express. Don't use it for applications that will be distributed to end users, where all the data will kept on each user's local system. It is a server-class engine, and works best when it can run on dedicated hardware.

Instead, you want a desktop-class or *in-process* database engine, such as Sqlite, Sql Server **Compact** (not Express) Edition, or even MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

There are many SQL engines that can be embedded in desktop application. For example SQLite, there should be one with C# interoperability.